Edge-coverings with copies of a directed cycle
Let $G$ be graph 44078 from the House of Graphs (https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/44078).
It turns out that the edges of $G$ can be covered with copies of a directed $4$-cycle, in such a way that every edge is traveled exactly once in each direction, and two $4$-cycles share at most one (undirected) edge.
This allows for a kind of "dual" by making each of the $4$-cycles a vertex and adding an edge between two $4$-cycles if they share an edge in $G$.
In this case(!) it turns out that the edges of the dual can be covered with copies of directed $5$-cycles (same conditions) and the dual of the dual is $G$ again.
Is there any literature about this kind of stuff? Neither Google nor ChatGPT are of much help (or I am not smart enough to formulate the proper requests). In order to exclude some trivial cases it is probably also necessary to require that no two $4$-cycles share more than $2$ vertices. One $4$-cycle is not allowed to travel a single edge in both directions.
Note: I was looking for an embedding of $G$ in the $3$-holed torus with only square faces. This would also allow a dual, but the concepts are probably different.
